# Terraform - Encrypting a db instance forces replacement

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-rds

I have a postgres RDS instance in AWS that I created using terraform.

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "..." {
  ...
}
```

Now I'm trying to encrypt that instance by adding

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "..." {
  ...
  storage_encrypted = true
}
```

But when I run `terraform plan`, it says that it's going to force replacement

```
# aws_db_instance.... must be replaced
...
~ storage_encrypted                     = false -> true # forces replacement
```

What can I do to prevent terraform from replacing my db instance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Terraform is not at fault here. You simply cannot change the encryption setting on an RDS instance after it was originally created, not with terraform, not via the AWS console or via any AWS API.
Instead you can / need to create a snapshot of the current db, copy + encrypt the snapshot and then restore from that snapshot: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/update-encryption-key-rds/

This will cause a downtime of the DB. And terraform does not do that for you automatically, you need to do this manually. After the DB is restored terraform should not longer try to replace the DB since the expected config now matches the actual config.

---

Technically you can `ignore_changes` the `storage_encrypted` property but of course that causes terraform to simply ignore any storage encryption changes.